# Периодический таймер дублируется в initState()

Tags: flutter

При переходе на другую страницу запускается периодический таймер в `initState()`. Но он почему-то дублируется.

Либо я делаю неправильный переход на другую страницу. Либо `initState()` задваивается.

Код перехода с одной страницы на другую:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => new MapPage(phone: _phone)));
```

Вызов таймера:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timerSendPointStart = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        makePoint();
      });
    });
  }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка и как правильно это должно быть реализовано?

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что в методе [dispose](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) вы останавливаете таймер.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timerSendPointStart?.cancel();
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я так и делаю, но ситуация не меняется. Возможно у меня проблема в логике кода...

1. На первой странице у меня есть `initState()`
2. Далее я перехожу на вторую страницу `Navigator.push`
3. На второй странице объявляю таймер, тоже использую `initState()` и в нем вызываю таймер, который начинает срабатывать два раза подряд

Если использовать `_timerSendPointStart?.cancel()` на второй странице, то таймер не останавливается. Если на первой, то он не запускается.

Comment: @Sergey Даже спустя 10 секунд не запускается? Как проверяете?

Comment: Простите, дезинформировал... Запускается в любом случае, даже если на двух страницах прописать в `dispose()`. Сейчас попробовал запустить таймер только на первой странице - работает корректно, запускается один раз. Отслеживаю через debug console (vs code)

Comment: Загрузил на гитхаб. Может так будет понятней). Первая страница https://github.com/Lightunit/flutter_mobile_new/blob/main/lib/main.dart Вторая страница https://github.com/Lightunit/flutter_mobile_new/blob/main/lib/mappage.dart

Comment: @Sergey мб в понедельник посмотрю, экспресс код ревью)

Comment: @Sergey Почему в проекте два main файла? Как его запустить?

Comment: Ещё линтер тут явно напрашивается.

Comment: Удалил лишний main, он не использовался. По поводу линтера, да согласен :)

Comment: @Sergey создай в корне проекта файл analysis_options.yaml с содержимым отсюда

https://gist.github.com/PopovVA/197d5cb3a61eb512ef4778a8195fb4f9

Comment: Точно улучшит кач-во кода.

Comment: Добавил в ветку dev, Вроде ничего не сломалось)

Comment: @Sergey Должно было появиться оч много варнингов

Comment: Около 50 я пофиксил (в main и mappage), Оставшиеся, я так думаю, не значительные

Comment: @Sergey Задебажить таймер удалось?

Comment: Таймер все так же срабатывает дважды моментально.

Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61057929/how-to-fix-flutter-web-timer-tick-twice-in-duration-given вычитал, что при переходе на другую страницу нужно убить iniState предыдущей страницы. Но пока не понимаю как это сделать и не уверен что это мой вариант

Comment: Как вариант перед переходом, делать _timerSendPointStart?.cancel.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123778/discussion-between-vadim-popov-and-sergey).